# C# - Can't use the SystemParameters, "type or namespace does not exist"

Tags: c#, namespaces

I use Visual Studio 2013 Professional, C#,
I have got these usings and that line in my code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;               
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

this.Width = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth;
```

However it has got an Error like "**The type or namespace name 'SystemParameters' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?)**"

I didnt really understand whats going on, should i add something more to use systemparamaters?

Comment: You can get the Height and Width of a form, check my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`System.Windows.SystemParameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemparameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class is defined in the `PresentationFramework.dll` assembly, which is part of the WPF UI Framework.

It is unclear from your question which UI framework are you targetting, but I presume it's winforms due to the presence of `using System.Windows.Forms` in your code.

Remove that using and [add the relevant assembly references](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7314433t%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to your project

Comment: @user3332706 dude, are you doing a WPF application or a winforms application? if WPF, then remove the reference to System.Windows.Forms and add references to `PresentationCore.dll`, `PresentationFramework.dll`, `WindowsBase.dll`, and `System.Xaml.dll`, otherwise you're looking at the wrong class.

Comment: its a windows forms application, cant I get screenwidth or screenheight?

Comment: @user3332706 Yes you can get Form Width and Height. `var height = this.Size.Height;` and `var width  = this.Size.Width; `

Answer (score 4):

Add the Reference `PresentationFramework` to your project, and add the `using System.Windows;` namespace to any file that needs to use `SystemParameters`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

To get ScreenWidth and ScreenHeight of a form, just do the following:

```
var height = this.Size.Height; //Gets the current Height of the Form.
var width  = this.Size.Width; //Gets the current Width of the Form.

this.Size = new Size(1000, 200); // Sets new Width/Height for form.
```

---

You need to reference the DLL. Also I have a feeling you created a `winforms` project when you actually want a `WPF Project`; you and are attempting to use a WPF component...

> PresentationFramework (presentationframework.dll) implements the
>   end-user presentational features, including layouts, time-dependent,
>   story-board based animations, and data binding.

**To add a project reference**

- In Solution Explorer, expand the project, right click on `References` and click `Add Reference`.
- Now click Browse on the bottom, find the DLL you are trying to use.
  In this case it should be included under `Assemblies - Framework`. Click on `Framework` on the left menu.
- Find `PresentationFramework` on the right. Make sure you **Check mark it**
- Click OK.

Now you have the reference, go back to your code and it should work. Again, make sure you create a `WPF Project` not `WinForms`...

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a reference to PresentationFramework.dll

Comment: @user3332706 PresentationFramework is missing there, you need to add it